# JIRA REST API call with oauth, where to put token?

Tags: rest, api, oauth, jira, jira-rest-api

after a successfull login via oauth  I'm receiving a bunch of data.

```
"oauth_token" => "07HQgsnnXaaaaaaaaaaki0GA9wGj2ThO"
"oauth_token_secret" => "2853FBbR5WbbbbbbbbbbIdQIMp5kmXVw" 
"oauth_expires_in" => "157680000" 
"oauth_session_handle" => "2a2ccccccccccKRiQmrl7EsPQd7f0QD7" 
"oauth_authorization_expires_in" => "160272000"
```

I would like to make api-calls to the rest api. In the Authentication-chapter of the documentation (https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/cloud/#auth/1/session-currentUser) it's listet that the oauth authentication is the prefered method.

In the liinked examples it's clear thet username:password authentication is way easier (https://developer.atlassian.com/jiradev/jira-apis/jira-rest-apis/jira-rest-api-tutorials). In fact in the whole documentation there are all examples with the easier username:password authentication( fred:fred). In my case I'm wondering how the token after a oauth-authentication is transfered in a request to the rest-api.

Do I have to add it to the header? With which name? Or do I have to append it to every url?

The only "valid" help in the documentation is this line, but here you cannot see how the access token is included into the request

```
java -jar rest-oauth-client-1.0.one-jar.jar request ACCESS_TOKEN JIRA_REST_URL
```

Has anyone solved this already? Where do I have to put the oauth_token?

Best Regards

Comment: How are you making the call? Are you using the official JRJC or doing it manually from your code?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I'm trying to do this with php, so no JRJC

Comment: No problem. Have you looked at/searched for PHP libraries to make OAuth2-backed web calls? I mean, there's nothing special about Jira, they conform to the normal Oauth2 spec

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the answer to the problem.
The process is good desccribed at https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/overview/creating-signatures

Best regards

Comment: Even this helps to for calculating the signature for each request, this doe not answer my initial question where to but the token/signature in the request to jira-rest api.

Answer (score 0):

You put it in the authorization header for every request like so:

```
var headers = {
    Authorization: 'Bearer ' + oauthToken
};
```

The ehaders object will be a parameter for your http client request. Depending on the framework you're using you can probably add it as default header configuration so it's added automatically for every request and you don't have to worry about it.

Comment: What is `Bearer` in your example?

Answer (score 0):

you need to create a token by following this instruction https://support.atlassian.com/atlassian-account/docs/manage-api-tokens-for-your-atlassian-account/

After the token is generated, you need to copy it. You can test it at Postman using Basic Auth with username as your email and password as the token.
[image]